# C - Data not received by serial device

Tags: c, serial-port

I am using C to open a serial device and send/receive data to/from it. Receiving works without a problem, but any data I send does not reach the device. I open the device like this:

```
int open_tty() {
    int fd = open("/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_CLOEXEC);  

    struct termios config;
    cfsetispeed(&config, B38400);
    cfsetospeed(&config, B38400);
    config.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;                                                                                                                                          
    config.c_cflag &= ~CSTOPB;                                                                                                                                          
    config.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE;                                                                                                                                           
    config.c_cflag |= CS8;                                                                                                                                              

    tcsetattr(fd, TCSANOW, &config);                                                         

    return fd;
}

...
write(fd, data, length)
...
```

According to strace, everything works just fine:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B38400 -opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B38400 -opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B38400 -opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
write(3, "some data.......", 16) = 16
```

However, the device does not receive any data (it should send an ACK packet). If I do the same thing in python, everything works just fine:

```
s=serial.Serial('/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=9600*4)
s.write('some data.......')
```

strace:

```
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/dev/ttyUSB0", O_RDWR|O_NOCTTY|O_NONBLOCK|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B38400 -opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B38400 -opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B38400 -opost isig icanon echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, SNDCTL_TMR_START or TCSETS, {B38400 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCGETS, {B38400 -opost -isig -icanon -echo ...}) = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCMBIS, [TIOCM_DTR])         = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCMBIS, [TIOCM_RTS])         = 0
ioctl(3, TCFLSH, TCIFLUSH)              = 0
write(3, "some data.......", 16) = 16
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:
As @abarnert suggested, I set the DTR and RTS bits and flushed the buffer:

```
char rts = TIOCM_RTS;
char dtr = TIOCM_DTR;
ioctl(fd, TIOCMBIS, &dtr);
ioctl(fd, TIOCMBIS, &rts);
tcflush(fd, TCIFLUSH);
```

This led to the following additional syscalls being dispatched directly before the `write` call:

```
ioctl(3, TIOCMBIS, [TIOCM_DTR|TIOCM_DSR|0x200]) = 0
ioctl(3, TIOCMBIS, [[TIOCM_RTS|0x30200}) = 0
ioctl(3, TCFLSH, TCIFLUSH)               = 0
```

However, I still don't get any ACK packet back from the device.

The device is a VirtualRobotix GPS uBlox 8 (http://www.virtualrobotix.it/index.php/en/shop/gps/3dr-gps-ublox-8-542015-11-30-13-35-34_-detail) connected using a USB to serial converter.

Comment: How do you *know* the "device" doesn't receive the data? Have you checked that everything works as it should on the other side?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude as I said, the device should send an ACK, which it does when I use python

Comment: Then perhaps consider doing some closer research about the difference in `strace` output? Especially about the `DTR` and `RTS` parts?

Comment: From the strace, the Python `serial` module is obviously doing three things you're not—setting the DTR and RTS bits, and then flushing. Have you tried doing the same things in C?

Comment: Meanwhile, without telling us anything more about what you're communicating with than "a serial device", it's hard to tell you _exactly_ what you _should_ be doing… but on a modem you use DTR (Data Terminal Ready) at the start of a session and RTS (Request To Send) to enable send flow, on a printer you use DTR to enable send flow, etc., so in generally these are pretty important.

Comment: And when you find the configuration that works, then please write an answer

Comment: @abarnert I am communicating with a GPS device; I'll try to implement the RTS and DTR, thank you

Comment: I'd start by digging through the datasheet of the GPS device then, and see what it actually expects. Hardware handshaking is not common nowadays, mostly these devices just work with some flavour of "AT commands", no parity, no handshaking, 8 bits.

Comment: when calling `open()`, always check (>=0) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.. When calling `write()`, always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: please post the actual GPS device and how it is connected to your hardware

Comment: @user3629249 I know that I have to check the return value, but I can see it in the strace output; the code here is just a minimalized version; my device is a virtualrobotix gps ublox 8 (http://www.virtualrobotix.it/index.php/en/shop/gps/3dr-gps-ublox-8-542015-11-30-13-35-34_-detail) connected to a usb to serial converter

Comment: The checking of the returned value from calls to C library functions should be in the source code so such checks are made when the application is running (for instance, in production)  so when you are not running `strace`, errors are still caught and handled

Comment: @user3629249 I know that, but like I said, the code I put here is stripped to the important parts

Comment: then, you should have mentioned that the error checking is stripped from the posted code,  Then I would not have even mentioned it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmmmm, I'm afraid you have not followed the correct procedure in setting `termios` parameters.  First you *must use* `tcgetattrs(3)` to get the actual configured parameters (and to initialize the `termios` structure, otherwise uninitialized to garbage in your code, as you have declared it as an automatic variable), then you change what you want, and finally you set the desired configuration.

The correct procedure is:

```
 struct termios param;
 res = tcgetattrs(fd, &param); /* VERY IMPORTANT: first get the actual parameters */
 if (res < 0) {
      perror("tegetattrs");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
 cfsetispeed(&param, B38400);
 cfsetospeed(&param, B38400);
 param.c_cflag &= ~PARENB;
 /* ... all the needed configuration. */
 /* and finally. */
 res = tcsetattrs(fd, &param);
 if (res < 0) { /* error */
     perror("tcsetattrs");
     exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
 }
```

(Also, it's common to check the return value `res` for errors)

as the manual page `termios(3)` says in relation to setting the line speed:

> ## Line speed
>
> The baud rate functions are provided for getting and setting the values
>     of the input and output baud rates in the `termios` structure.  The
>     new values **do not take effect until `tcsetattr()` is successfully
>     called**.
>
> Setting the speed to `B0` instructs the modem to "hang up".  The actual
>     bit rate corresponding to `B38400` may be altered with `setserial(8)`.
>
> The input and output baud rates **are stored in the `termios` structure**.

(quotation is mine)